# Need advice for object detection and motion classification on real time video

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, object-detection, yolo

I'm in research for my final project, i want to make object detection and motion classification like amazon go, i have read lot of research like object detection with SSD or YOLO and video classification using CNN+LSTM, i want to propose training algorithm like this:

1. Real time detection for multiple object (in my case: person) with SSD/YOLO
2. Get the boundary object and crop the frame
3. Feed cropped frame info to CNN+LSTM algo to make motion prediction (if the person's walking/taking items)

is it possible to make it in real-time environment?
or is there any better method for real-time detection and motion classification

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use it in real-time application, several other things must be considered which are not appeared before implementation of algorithm in real environment.

About your 3-step proposed method, it already could be result in a good method, but the first step would be very accurate. I think it is better to combine the 3 steps in one step. Because the motion type of person is a good feature of a person. Because of that, I think all steps could be gathered in one step.

My idea is as follows:
1. a video classification dataset which just tag the movement of person or object
2. cnn-lstm based video classification method

This would solve your project properly.

This answer need to more details, if u interested in, I can answer u in more details.

Comment: thank you for your response, i thought like that too, but if we're just using cnn+lstm, does it took big computation over image-per-frame, because the image is large, and if we crop the detected object first would it be a cheap computation and more accurate in testing?

Comment: yes, you are somehow correct, but as u want to just to recognize between person and object, and you have video frame, by using some series of video frame, because of movement of people, you can detect person in the top first layer of your neural network too which is not so costly. May be my proposed method has some problems, If yes, I would be happy if you notify me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Had pretty much the same problem. Motion prediction does not work that well in complex real-life situations. Here is a simple one:

[image]
([See in action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yVkpX5EOVr0))

I'm building a 4K video processing tool ([some examples](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCLsVHuYpywKFNAHKFfImIVg/videos)). Current approach looks like the following:

1. do rough but super fast segmentation
2. extract bounding box and shape
3. apply some "meta vision magic"
4. do precise segmentation within identified area

[image]
([See in action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6YQFawMJG9w))

As of now the approach looks way more flexible comparing to motion tracking.

"Meta vision" intended to properly track shape evolution: 
[image]
([See in action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zucO4Zin-wM))

Let's compare:

- [Meta vision disabled](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vJjBv5-pWyk)
- [Meta vision enabled](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0mYlrQTJ7wY)

Comment: wow such amazing job, the precision is so good and it's so fast with 4k video, i wonder what segmentation method do you use?what is meta vision? any paper related?

Comment: i don't think it's simple what you have done,so i want to discuss my case what if i use pose estimation (deep pose, etc) and feed value from the method into cnn+lstm

Comment: I use a custom implementation of multi color image segmentation based on delta E. As for the "meta vision" it is just an internal name for a cross frame object tracking. 

Your case is quite tricky (due to time limits, etc), so any two-step approach including (1) fast but rough results later used to narrow down area for (2) precise but time-consuming processing is worth trying.

Comment: Let's pretend you have 8K stream (we should build for the future anyway). It goes without saying you have to identify smaller areas for any further complex processing (step #1). All smaller areas can be evaluated in parallel using a bit more complex logic. Are you going to do some experiments or build a tiny PoC?